# React JS Error "...rest" Syntax error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-router, react-router-redux

I am new to React and looking at this ReactTraining.  I would like to make some of my paths private (that way you can only view them when you are logged in).  I am able to authenticate users fine and direct them to a new page, but now I would like to "Protect" that page so that it is only accessible after logging in.  I found a few different [sources](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-website/modules/examples/Auth.js) that seem to use the same "PrivateRoute" function below.  Everything seems to work great so far (and makes sense), except for the "...rest" part of this following code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/Login"
    at webpackMissingModule (router.js:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (router.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18b9132…:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 18b9132…:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18b9132…:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 18b9132…:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 18b9132…:578)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18b9132…:555)
    at bootstrap 18b9132…:578
webpackMissingModule @ router.js:9
(anonymous) @ router.js:9
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 18b9132…:555
fn @ bootstrap 18b9132…:86
(anonymous) @ index.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 18b9132…:555
fn @ bootstrap 18b9132…:86
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 18b9132…:578
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 18b9132…:555
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 18b9132…:578
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 18b9132…:578
webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./src/components/Login.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (16:46)

  14 | 
  15 | 
> 16 | const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
     |                                               ^
  17 | <Route {...rest} render={props => (
  18 |   fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
  19 |     <Component {...props}/>

 @ ./src/router.js 25:13-42
```

It appears that I am importing everything that I should be so my thought is that I don't have something installed that should be.

Does anyone know what I may need to install to resolve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [spread `...` syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) is not part of the `es2015` or `react` babel presets. It's currently a stage 3 proposal. To enable support for spread in your React project, install the babel stage 3 plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3
```

and add it to your `.babelrc`:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Worked great!